# call someone on

Tags: meaning

> **He called me on the stage.**

What does this sentence above mean?

1. He called me to get on the stage.
2. He called me when I was on the stage.
3. Either 1 or 2 according to context.

I would choose 3.

If **"me"** was waiting to get on the stage, then, 1 is the correct option.

If **"me"** was already on the stage, then, 2 is the correct option.

Lastly, is the ambiguity resolved if I wrote the sentence as **"He called me ( upon/ up on) the stage"**  so as to make the original sentence mean sentence 1?

I want to get answers as many as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be either, depending on context, but leaning toward the first sentence.

The more common interpretation uses the definition of "call" that is short for "call to someone to request they do something", which in this case would be:

> He **called** to **me** to ask me to come up **on** the **stage**

Similar uses:

> The mother **called** the kids **over to** the picnic table.
>
> She **called** me **up to** her family's summer house in the country.
>
> The boy **called** the dog **out of** the neighbor's garden.

The ambiguity is definitely resolved if you use "up on"

> He called me **up on** the stage (with him).

however the other interpretation normally takes some kind of adverbial phrase to explain what exactly is going on:

> He called me **while I was on stage**.

Otherwise it could mean that he called me while *he* was on the stage.

> He called me **from** on stage.

Comment: Just as a little-off-topic question, does **"He asked me on the stage"** sound ambigous in the same way as **"He called me on the stage"**?

Comment: @SinK  Again by default you would lean toward the first interpretation.  If you meant the second, you would need more information:  *"A: Where did he ask you to marry him?  B: He asked me **from** on stage"*

Answer (score 1):

It is both ambiguous and awkward.

To be explicit, I would use one of the following:

> He called me **onto** the stage.
>   He called me **from** the stage.

---

In no normal interpretation does it mean "he called me while I was on the stage."